# How to convert a Trunctated RSS Feed to a Full Text RSS Feed?

Tags: rss, implementation, full-text-search, truncated

I just found a cool web app named "[Full Text RSS Feed](http://fulltextrssfeed.com/)", it can convert a truncated RSS feed to a full text RSS feed. I just used it to convert several sites' feeds, it so practical web app that I love it very much.

Here I wanted to know how to implement this function? What's the mechanism of it?

I have found a Yahoo! Pipe [Full Text RSS Builder](http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.info?_id=f9ef30e9f3b6b905777deae6d24727a6), I don't know if this is the backend of the app I mentioned in the first paragraph. I try this pipe with the same truncated RSS feed I just used in that app, but got different result. I also notice that the pipe author will upgrade the version to v2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might also try FeedsAPI a [**Full Text RSS Feeds Generator**](http://www.feedsapi.com)  with some advance features and a great user experience.